# Fragment reloads every tab click in Bottom Navigation View

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, components

I implemented a BottomNavigationView with navigation controller

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);

NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);
```

in which I have 3 tabs:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zkjw.png)

The idea is that the fragments for every tab reloads every time I change the tab. For the second tab I will have a list with many items and I don't want it to be reloaded every time I open that tab.

I am not sure which is the procedure to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a `ViewPager` - this avoids reloading your fragment which usually occurs if you're using fragment transactions. To give you a brief idea, please take a look [here](https://github.com/tendaimaswaya/BottomNavigationProject) (Unfortunately its written in Kotlin but maybe you'll get an idea)

Comment: I would like to keep using the navigation components. Wouldn't using view pager change the method to implement it ?